# How can I identify inconsistencies and outliers in a dataset in R

Tags: r, outliers

I have a big dataset with alot of columns, being most of them not numeric values. I need to find inconsistencies in the data as well as outliers and the part of obtaining inconsistencies would be easy if the dataset wasn't so big (7032 rows to be exact).

An inconsistency would be something like: ID supposed to be 4 letters and 4 numbers and I obtain something else (like 3 numbers and 2 letters); or other example would be a number that should be a 0 or 1 and I obtain a -1 or a 2 .

Is there any function that I can use to obtain the inconsitencies in each column?
For the specific columns that doesn't have numeric values, I thought of doing a regex and validate if each row for a certain column is valid but I didn't found info that could give me that.

For the part of outliers I did a boxplot to see if I could obtain any outlier, like this:

```
boxplot(dataset$column)
```

But the graphic didn't gave me any outliers. Should I be ok with the results that I obtain in the graphic or should I try something else to see if there is really any outlier in the data?

Comment: Unfortunately this question as posed is way too broad. The definition of "inconsistency" and "outlier" is highly variable and problem-dependent. You can use a tool like OpenRefine https://openrefine.org/ to explore and clean your data in a principled way ... if you want help here you'll probably have to give some **specific** examples of what you would consider an "inconsistency" and/or an "outlier", then maybe people can help you develop code to detect those cases.

Comment: Given that this site is really to offer coding help, I think you need to take one step back and ask what metrics might be useful here.  We can help you implement a solution once you know what you want in theory, but this is the wrong forum for asking statistics questions.  You should post this question or one like it on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).  A good start would be to look at [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37865/is-there-a-simple-way-of-detecting-outliers).

Comment: @BenBolker I don't need to clean data, I only need to indentify "inconsistencies" and "outliers" in the dataset. 
Answering you of what I consider as an inconsistency, is a value that goes above or down the values that I consider "valid". An example would be like an id that has 4 numbers and 4 letters, if I obtain a value "4444-LLLL" this would be a consistent value in my data, if I recieved something like "444-LLLL" this would be inconsistent. Other example would be something like a numeric value that is suposed to be 0 or 1 and I have a 2 or -1.

Comment: Yeah I get it now. It's just because this is all new to me and I'm trying to understand how to obtain some specific things. I will try to rephrase the question so it is easier to be answered.

Comment: Better. The last part of your question is still too vague to be answerable. If you don't see anything that the standard box-whisker definition identifies as an 'outlier' that may or may not be appropriate to identify 'inconsistent' points - depends what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific examples you've given:

- an ID must be be four numbers and 4 letters:

```r
!grepl("^[0-9]{4}-[[:alpha:]]{4}$", ID)
```

will be TRUE for inconsistent values (`^` and `$` mean beginning- and end-of-string respectively; `{4}` means "previous pattern repeats exactly four times"; `[0-9]` means "any symbol between 0 and 9 (i.e. any numeral); `[[:alpha:]]` means "any alphabetic character"). If you only want *uppercase* letters you could use `[A-Z]` instead (assuming you are not working in some weird locale like Estonian).

- If you need a numeric value to be 0 or 1, then `!num_val %in% c(0,1)` will work (this will work for any set of allowed values; you can use it for a specific set of allowed character values as well)
- If you need a numeric value to be between `a` and `b` then `!(a < num_val & num_val < b)` ...

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to get actually. Thank you @BenBolker.